# PE ratios in regression models - How to deal with unprofitable companies?

Tags: regression

*First of all the following is for personal project, not to actually trade, so I'm under no illusion that a simple regression is going to make me money.*

Pretty simple question: Suppose you're fitting a simple regression model with the most recent  PE ratio being one factor.

The problem obviously arises that if a company is unprofitable its PE ratio is undefined (or, if calculated using the normal definition, leads to inconsistent ordering due to negative PE).

I'm curious how one normally deals with this?

My two ideas would be to either:

1. Set unprofitable companies to have a large PE ratio $M>0$ such that $M$ is larger than the PE of any profitable company in the dataset
2. Introduce a dummy variable $Profit$ that is $1$ if the company is profitable, $0$ otherwise. And replace the $PE$ variable in the regression with

$$PE:Profit + Profit$$

Since this includes an intercept to distinguish profitable and unprofitable companies, and also includes a PE slope for companies where PE is defined.

General thoughts on this issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the $EP$ ratio instead, with $EP = \frac{1}{PE}$. Now your ordering will be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe that didn't occur to me!